# Are There Any VNC Servers that Work with Cinnamon DE 3 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, vnc, cinnamon

## Background

I need to remote in from Windows to Ubuntu 16.04, using Cinnamon DE 3.2.2.

However, when I try to get VNC set up, everything fails. After researching, I've found that it's because Cinnamon uses acceleration of some type.

## What I've Tried

I've tried RealVNC, TightVNC, TigerVNC. I just get a black screen on the VNC Viewer.

I've tried using RDP, and I was able to get in, but only by using the Gnome Session Flashback, which caused me to just be using Gnome instead of Cinnamon, defeating the purpose.

Teamviewer ... costs money for non-personal use.

[image]

## Question

Is there any VNC server (or any methods in general of remotely viewing the desktop) that work with the current, accelerated Cinnamon Desktop (3.2.2), running on Ubuntu 16.04?

---

## Edit

Here is a screencap of what is happening. I am using VirtualBox to host the machine, on my Windows 10 computer. On the right is my VNC viewer program, which is Real VNC.

[image]

---

## Edit 2

Content of output in Terminal, after VNC makes connection:

```
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Got connection from client 192.168.10.92
22/12/2016 08:49:41   other clients:
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Normal socket connection
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Disabled X server key autorepeat.
22/12/2016 08:49:41   to force back on run: 'xset r on' (3 times)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 incr accepted_client=1 for 192.168.10.92:56946  sock=12
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Client Protocol Version 3.8
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Protocol version sent 3.8, using 3.8
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: executing handler for type 1
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: returning securityResult for client rfb version >= 3.8
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000016)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000015)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x0000000F)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xFFFFFEC6)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.10.92
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 192.168.10.92
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Using ZRLE encoding for client 192.168.10.92
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Pixel format for client 192.168.10.92:
22/12/2016 08:49:41   8 bpp, depth 8
22/12/2016 08:49:41   uses a colour map (not true colour).
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000016)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000015)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x0000000F)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xFFFFFEC6)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.10.92
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 192.168.10.92
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Switching from ZRLE to raw Encoding for client 192.168.10.92
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x0000000F)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000016)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000015)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xFFFFFEC6)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.10.92
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 192.168.10.92
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Switching from raw to hextile Encoding for client 192.168.10.92
22/12/2016 08:49:41 Pixel format for client 192.168.10.92:
22/12/2016 08:49:41   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
22/12/2016 08:49:41   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
22/12/2016 08:49:41 no translation needed
22/12/2016 08:49:41 client 1 network rate 1891.4 KB/sec (1891.4 eff KB/sec)
22/12/2016 08:49:41 client 1 latency:  0.5 ms
22/12/2016 08:49:41 dt1: 0.0002, dt2: 0.0093 dt3: 0.0005 bytes: 17694
22/12/2016 08:49:41 link_rate: LR_LAN - 1 ms, 1891 KB/s
22/12/2016 08:49:41 client useCopyRect: 192.168.10.92 -1
22/12/2016 08:49:41 client_set_net: 192.168.10.92  0.0042
22/12/2016 08:49:41 created   xdamage object: 0x3400040
22/12/2016 08:49:42 cursor_noshape_updates_clients: 0
22/12/2016 08:49:44 cursor_noshape_updates_clients: 0
22/12/2016 08:49:49 cursor_noshape_updates_clients: 0
22/12/2016 08:49:50 created selwin: 0x3400041
22/12/2016 08:49:50 called initialize_xfixes()
22/12/2016 08:49:52 cursor_noshape_updates_clients: 0
```

Comment: Added output, David.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried TeamViewer?

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/

I use in my debian with openbox and it works fine.

Comment: "Teamviewer ... costs money for non-personal use."

Comment: Cool, I didn't know your environment.

Comment: Have you tried: chmod 775 xstartup ? in the /home/user/.vnc/xstartup file

Comment: I'm quoting because I said that in my question. I can't use Teamviewer because my boss doesn't want to pay money. Right now the machine is using Ubuntu 5 or something really old like that. And he is used to having completely free remote access. Teamviewer is hundreds of dollars for a corporate use, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As Cinnamon Desktop is a fork of Gnome Shell and `x11vnc` works well on my system I'd say the issue on yours is not the window compositor.

When you start the VNC server from an SSH session (or any other terminal session that wasn't spawned from an X11 session) you need to tell it which X11 display to use, e. g.:

```
x11vnc -display :0
```

or

```
DISPLAY=:0 x11vnc
```

Other VNC server may use different ways to specify the display but they should accept the `DISPLAY` environment variable by convention.

`x11vnc` also allows “symbolic” display names based on the account name of the user owning the X session. It can also create new X sessions on a virtual Xfvb display device. For more see the description of the `-display` option in the [`x11vnc(1)` manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/x11vnc.1.html).

---

You can also try [Vino](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vino/), a GUI configuration interface to provide remote (VNC) access to a currently running desktop session.

Comment: I went back to my saved image of Cinnamon without any VNC installed, and installed x11vnc. Then I tried both of your lines of code. They don't appear to be changing settings. They launch the server. However, what I see is still just a black screen. I'm updating my question to show a screencap.